# git commit not merge in the leatest commit github

Tags: git, github

I commit the changes using Git, but I don't see the new commits and changes in Github repository, and after push again i got message that says everything is up to date in Git.

i run this command:

```
git push origin master
```

result:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

[image]

---

Note 1: i use different system pc for my commit

Note 2: i think this problem for tree

Comment: Can you show the output of `git log --oneline --decorate` on your machine?

Comment: Perhaps you made a `git commit` but forgot to say `git add` first? (I make that mistake quite a lot. I suppose I ought to use `git commit -a` but I just can't bring myself to do it.)

Comment: Also, unclear what your two notes mean. What does "use different system pc for my commit" mean? You cannot commit on one machine and push on another machine, so I hope it doesn't mean that. And I don't know what "problem for tree" means at all.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are doing 'git push' without add and commit.
Run these commands before 'git push'

1. git add .
2. git commit -m "type your commit message"

And now you can 'git push'

3. git push -u origin master

Make sure to run above 3 codes every time before pushing to repository

Reason is, git commit is for Local repository and git push is for remote repository. [See Difference](https://blog.mergify.com/git-commit-vs-push-whats-the-difference/). So if you didn't commit before push, means your local repository still haven't updated. So basically you are trying to push not updated local repository to the remote repository . Hope this solves the misunderstanding

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).